# notifications/error handling in marionettejs

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm building an application using Marionette, I'm trying to write come with an idea/pattern for handling notification on the application.
What I mean is when the user does some action we should show some notification(success/error), if an error occurs in  the application we should show some notification.
I was wandering what is the best way/approach in handling some cases.
If you have some experience/link or any information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use events. You can see an example here:

https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_view.js : a view triggers an event (e.g. delete a model)

https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js : the controller listen for and processes that event. The same concept should be used for success/failure/error management.

There's an example of using events to manage routing in the [free sample](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).