# Right Use for Backbone Marionette CompositeView

Tags: marionette

I have the following question/dilemma:
I'm creating a menu something similar to menu in the left top corner in Facebook (find request, Inbox, notifications), I'm using Backbone Marionette CompositeView.
The problem I have is that when I click in some item I add/remove css class in the clicked element, How I inform to the other items that they need to remove css class if have it, in the clicked ItemView doesn't know about the existence of the other elements.
I have a solution in:

```
    <script id="ulTemplate" type="text/template">
    <ul class="ulItem">
    </ul>
</script>
<script id="internal-Item" type="text/template">    
    <div class="<%= className %>"></div>
</script>    
<div class="container">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omher/hQeuD/
but I don't like it/think is the right one
What do you think?
If not How I inform the other elements that other element was clicked?
using events?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use events. See my answer to your other question here: [notifications/error handling in marionettejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881304/notifications-error-handling-in-marionettejs)

In your example, each `div` should be an item view, and on `click` should (e.g.) `MyApp.trigger("div1:clicked")`. Then, in your controller, you need

```
MyApp.on("div1:clicked", function(){
  // adapt the CSS classes of the parent element here
})
```